# waitForMessage functionality for TimeSyncronizer

Tags: ros, topic, callbackqueue, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am interested to get new sensor values (published to a topic) while in a service callback. For a single topic I was able to do this using ros::topic::waitForMessage. Unfortunately I am actually looking for a pair of images + camera information (4 topics in total) that I synchronize using message_filters::TimeSyncronizer. Is there a way to wait (block) for the next synchronized set while in a service callback?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11120/waitformessage-functionality-for-timesyncronizer/) by [dk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1043/dk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2011-09-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no 'shortcut' such as ros::topic::waitForMessage for the message time synchronizer. You'll have to construct your own mechanism where you connect to the topics from the service callback, and monitor the callback of the time synchronizer.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1043/dk/) on 2011-09-23**:
I tried this but it did not work. The callback (given to TimeSyncronizer) does not get called while the service callback is active. Looking at the implementation of waitForMessage it seems I need to specify a different CallbackQueue, but I could not figure out how to do this for TimeSynchronizer.